# IFS variable in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Dears,
Any idea why i am seeing blank value for IFS variable.

```
bash-4.2$ set | grep -i ifs
IFS=$' \t\n'

bash-4.2$ echo $IFS

bash-4.2$
bash-4.2$
```

Comment: Um, what else do you _expect_ to see?

Comment: I expect to see this IFS=$' \t\n' in echo $IFS

Comment: But that's not what it has.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing a blank value because **that's what *is* always stored in IFS**: it contains a space (invisible), a tab (also invisible), and a line-feed (invisible too).

It does not contain a dollar sign, nor any backslashes, nor any letters: that's simply how `set` tries to display a variable that contains invisible characters. So he `\t` represents a tab and the `\n` represents a line break, and the surrounding `$'...'` indicates that the backslash combinations are to be interpreted as special characters and not as literal text.

`set` uses this specific format because it can also be given *back* to the shell as part of some other command. For example, run `echo $'Hello\tworld!` would print a tab where the `\t` is. And actually *running* `IFS=$' \t\n'` as a command would indeed set the IFS variable to space + tab + linebreak.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `\t` and `\n` are parsed on input and converted to the actual character codes. So the output of `echo $IFS` looks like spaces (and some are removed by argument parsing since you didn't quote). If you want to see the actual contents, convert to hex, and don't forget to quote to avoid characters being parsed out:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
printf '%s' "$IFS" | hd
00000000  20 09 0a                                          | ..|
00000003
0
```